# How do I close a JDialog with the behavior I want?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I am just beginning to learn Java so please be gentle with me. I find the default close behaviors of frames and dialogs confusing.

I am trying to create a simple login dialog box using Swing. I have taken a `JDialog` for the dialog box. I just want that when the user clicks the **Login** button, after doing the authentication stuff, I want the login window to close but another window to open.

If, however, the user clicks the **Close** button, the login box should close but also the application must end.

I know how to write action listeners and the authentication code. I just need help with understanding what close behavior I must implement.

Here is my code so far (only the relevant snippets). More specific questions are in the comments near the action listeners.

```
package practice.bookyard.client;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LoginDialogEventLoop());     
    }

}


public class LoginDialogEventLoop implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Create and set title
        JDialog dialog = new LoginDialog("Bookyard Login");

        // Set default close behavior
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        // Set size
        dialog.setSize(400, 300);
        // dialog.setResizable(false);

        // Set position on the screen
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        dialog.setLocation((int)screenSize.getWidth() / 2, (int)screenSize.getHeight() / 2);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

}

public class LoginDialog extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected JLabel lblTopSpace = null;
    protected JPanel loginPanel = null;
    protected JPanel statusPanel = null;

    public LoginDialog(String title) {

        super((Dialog)null);

        this.setTitle(title);

        Initialize();
    }

    protected void Initialize() {

        // DONE: add a panel and add controls to the panel
        ...
    }
}





public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected JLabel lblUserName;
    protected JLabel lblPassword;
    protected JTextField txtUserName;
    protected JPasswordField txtPassword;
    protected JButton btnLogin;
    protected JButton btnCancel;

    public LoginPanel() {
        super();

        this.Initialize();
    }

    protected void Initialize() {

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        // Create controls
        lblUserName = new JLabel("User Name: ");
        lblPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
        txtUserName = new JTextField(15);
        txtPassword = new JPasswordField(15);
        txtPassword.setEchoChar('*');
        btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

        // Set them on the panel using the constraints
        // 3 rows, 3 columns
        // DONE ALREADY
        ...



        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // authenticate user: I know how to do this

                // how do I close the login JDialog
                // of course, I will need a reference to the dialog here
                // which is not a big deal. I can have that be passed
                // in via a constructor.
                // So, supposing this 'dialog' variable represented the
                // login dialog
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog((Dialog)null);

                // What's the method to close this window?
                // I believe it is dispose()
                // But will calling the dispose method also
                // exit the main thread since this is the 
                // only window in the application?
                // Also, should I be launching the new window from here?
                // or from within the main() of the application?
                // Is there a way this dialog can communicate to its
                // creator what the dialog result was -- Login or Cancel?
                dialog.dispose();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("New Window");
                frame.setSize(400,  400);
                frame.setVisible(true);


            }
        });

        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // So, supposing this 'dialog' variable represented the
                // login dialog
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog((Dialog)null);

                // This one is a bit easier
                // But since this is a JDialog and not a JFrame
                // I cannot set the default close behavior
                // to EXIT_ON_DISPOSE. I can only set it to:
                // HIDE ON DISPOSE
                // CLOSE ON DISPOSE
                // DO NOTHING ON DISPOSE
                // And since I have set it to CLOSE ON DISPOSE in Program.java
                // just calling dispose() on this will keep the application
                // still alive, right?
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider a modal dialog? IMHO, with a modal JDialog it’s much easier to control what happens when the user closes the dialog one way or the other. If you don’t know what it is or how to do, consult the tutorials.

Comment: Yes, I started with the idea that I would make this modal, but since this is the first ever dialog in the application, it will have no parent / owner. And when you create a new `JDialog` with the `owner` parameter as `null`, you cannot call the overload of the `JDialog` ctor that accepts the boolean `modal` parameter.

Comment: Sorry, @WaterCoolerv2, I wasn’t aware of that.

Comment: This works for me: `new JDialog(null, "Ole’s title", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL).setVisible(true);`. Except the dialog is very small and hides in the far corner of my screen.

Comment: Sure, I did that but that doesn't answer my question. In both the cases, Login and Cancel click, it will close the application. My immediate question is: where do I launch the new form if the login succeeds -- just after the call to `dialog.dispose()` in the login click listener or in the method that created the login dialog? And if I launch it in the method that created the dialog, won't that other window open up even in the case of Cancel click?

Comment: Ok, I just created a new frame just after the call to `dispose()` in the login click listener and it works. For now, this will suffice as the answer. In the longer term, though, I think I might have to read up 200 pages or so before I understand what's happening.

Comment: This would be relatively easy to do with a `JOptionPane` (a form of modal dialog). Where is the attempt to open the frame?

Comment: *Where is the attempt to open the frame?* I did that after posting this question. It was not illustrated in the question. I have now updated the question with that. I think that solves it for now.

Comment: @OleV.V. Many thanks :-)

Comment: *"I think that solves it for now"* Glad you got it sorted. :)

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).